Branch.io doesn't redirect to IOS App Store directly when app is not installed
When the app is installed, the deeplink works perfectly fine (redirects user to the app directly). However, when the app is not installed, the deeplink doesn't open IOS App Store directly, it opens a website first, and user has to click "Get the App" to open the App Store. How to remove this one extra step, bypass the website and redirect user directly to the IOS App Store?


This is Shravan from Branch Support. Please note, that the screen/deep view page you are viewing is a NativeLink™ page which you have enabled in the Branch dashboard for iOS configurations.
NativeLink™ is an innovation from Branch that bridges the gap created by Private Relay with an on-device solution that does not require the use of an IP address for deferred deep linking.
Learn more about it here: https://help.branch.io/using-branch/docs/nativelink-deferred-deep-linking
You can disable this on your Branch dashboard by navigating as follows:
Dashboard --> Configuration --> Enable NativeLink™ (Un-check the mark).
For any additional details or clarifications, please write to support@branch.io.
